# How to get a count of the people who viewed my profile?

Tags: support

I do not wish to know the names as I respect privacy. I only want a count. How do I see that? I want to know how many people have actually been impressed enough with my answers to go and check my other answers. It might give me a sense of satisfaction that I have helped the society with my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

It is reported right in your profile page, on https://english.stackexchange.com/users/239082/himabindu-boddupalli.

> [image: screenshot]

It says *76 profile views*, in the screenshot.

I don't recall if that is the number of unique visits (i.e. the number of different users that viewed the profile since the account was created) or it considers as different the views done from the same user after X hours (e.g. if I view a profile two different days, the number of views is increased by two.

There isn't any tooltip to explain the value, so it could be either.

I found [How are profile views counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted) but there isn't an answer from a Stack Exchange developer; it doesn't help in knowing for sure how the profile views are counted.
It doesn't count when you view your own profile, as [Can "user profile views" NOT include narcissism please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please) explains.

Don't get confused from *people reached*, which has a tooltip describing it as:

> Estimated number of times people viewed helpful posts by this user (based on page views of questions and questions where they wrote highly-ranked answers)